# How to remove lines in a Matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I want remove the graph in animation,
when the text line is more then 19 lines..

My code has referred to [this video](https://youtu.be/ZmYPzESC5YY)
If the text line is more than 19 lines, the graph is remove.

I was use the `remove()` and `del`, but this isn't working because using `remove()` and `del` in this code will not automatically delete the graph.

When the text line is more than 19 lines, the graph remove when the matplotlib is re-executed.

I also tried use `plt.cla`, `plt.clf` but this things.. 
removing the label too.. i don't want remove the label and title

how can i fix it? .

Here is my code :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.xlim(-190,190)
plt.ylim(-190,190)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('data.txt', 'r').read()    
    lines = graph_data.split('\n') 
    xs = []
    ys = []

    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',') 
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)

    ax1.plot(xs, ys, 'r')

    if (graph_data.count(' \n')+1) >=19: 
       ax1.lines[0].remove() 
       ##del ax1.lines[0] 
       ##plt.cla()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval=1, frames=2, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning a variable to the value of the lines count function as in:

```
return_value = graph_data.count(' \n')+1
```

Print this value and see if the count function is working properly as you add lines 
hope this helps.

Comment: count is walking, and Among remove(), del, and plt.cla, only plt.cla works.